# UriTemplate prefix for RESTful WCF web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, rest

I have various interfaces (endpoints) in a WCF service host, each for a completely different concern. In a classic soapy web service, I'm able to define a base host address (e.g. `http://myhost.com/`) and map each interface to a relative URI (`IServiceContract` -> `service/`, `IMaintenanceContract` -> `maintenance/`) so I can call them by e.g. `http://myhost.com/service/mymethod`.

Now I'm taking my first steps towards a RESTful WCF service using JSON as message format for CRUD web requests and the only thing I see to address an operation is by using the `UriTemplate` field from `WebInvoke` (or `WebGet`) attribute. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that I can put this on the interface, just on operation contract methods.

How can I map each interface to a different relative `URI`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you'll put the base url on the [OperationContract] methods.  This is OK though, because you can specify any base url you want.  Here is a sample interface that gives you this control.

```
namespace MyHostApi
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyHostApi
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                UriTemplate = "WhateverYouWant/HelloWorld/{name}")]
        string HelloWorld(string format, string name);

    }
}
```